Sorting an Array of Objects in Python using different methods
I have an array of footballers with several attributes e.g. name, position, country, number of goals etc.
I want to use the bubbleSort algorithm on the array and sort by name or by any another attribute without writing the bubblesort again for each method.
My class:
class euroPlayer():
  def __init__(self,name,position,age, club,height,foot,caps,goals,value,country):
    self._name=name
    self._position=position
    self._age=age
    self._club=club
    self._height=height
    self._foot=foot
    self._caps=caps
    self._goals=goals
    self._value=value
    self._country=country

 

 def getName(self):
    return self._name

  def setName(self,new):
    self._name=new

  def getPosition(self):
    return self._position

Sort for the names:
def bubbleSort(list):
  swap=True
  n=len(list)
  while swap:
    swap=False
    for j in range(n-1):
      if list[j].getName()>list[j+1].getName:
        list[j],list[j+1]=list[j+1],list[j]
        swap=True
    n=n-1
  return list

How do I make it work for a different getter.

Those getter/setter methods are terribly unpythonic and superfluous to begin with. But even with those, you can pass the name of a getter method as argument to your bubbleSort and use getattr. But the much more pythonic answer is that euroPlayer should implement __gt__ at the class level, and your algorithm should just do list[j] > list[j+1].

You could insert a function for the comparison as a parameter for the sort function. When calling the sort algorithm, you only have to pass another comparison method.

"I want to use the bubbleSort algorithm" - Why?

@deceze How would __gt__ support multiple different orders?

As a side note, don't name your variables the same as built-in methods and functions (e.g., list, dict, etc.), and try to follow PEP 8 guidelines in general (use snake_case instead of camelCase for method names, etc.).

@nocomment I was thinking in terms of trying to reuse that sorting algorithm for different objects. You're right, it doesn't help trying to sort the same object by a different key.

You can pass a function to the bubbleSort function to extract the attribute:
def bubbleSort(list, key):
    swap = True
    n = len(list)
    while swap:
        swap = False
        for j in range(n - 1):
            if key(list[j]) > key(list[j + 1]):
                list[j], list[j + 1] = list[j + 1], list[j]
                swap = True
        n = n - 1
    return list

To use it pass a lambda expression to extract the attribute you want:
sorted_by_name = bubbleSort(players, key=lambda p: p.getName())
sorted_by_goals = bubbleSort(players, key=lambda p: p.getGoals())

Alternatively (as @no-comment suggested) you can directly pass the method reference:
sorted_by_name = bubbleSort(players, key=euroPlayer.getName)
sorted_by_goals = bubbleSort(players, key=euroPlayer.getGoals)


key=euroPlayer.getName should also work, no need to lambda-wrap it (but I haven't tested it).

Would be nice to make key optional and have it try to use intrinsic object order if no key function is provided. But then again, this is probably just learning code and not supposed to be production ready…

@nocomment You are correct, it does work
